# Why are new compounds in materials science investigated and categorized under low-temperature thermodynamic properties?

Tags: material-science, nanoscience

Is it solely because these materials are usually not as interesting in ambient temperatures?

Comment: That is an extraordinary broad statement to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is usually because those new materials are often candidates for cryogenic superconductors.